# Storing SQL Conditions in JSON

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, json

I have a use-case where I want to search all the `SQL` queries on an entity in database, and later I want to query on which fields and for which values that query had been executed. I am developing this in ruby.

For example, Following queries were ran:

```
select * from entity where created_at > "2015-03-01" and  created_at < "2015-03-03" ;
select * from entity where created_at > "2015-03-03" and  created_at < "2015-03-04" and type in ('forward');
select * from entity where created_at > "2015-03-01" and  created_at < "2015-03-03" and type in ('reverse');
```

Later on, I should be able to fetch for which dates on `created_at`, these queries were ran. This can be queried for type as well, so want to keep it completely generic.

So, I was thinking to save conditions of these queries in `JSON` format. Let me know if you know of any format or `gem`, which can help for such case.

I was thinking of constructing `JSON` for these queries in following format:

```
{
    "query": [
        {
            "field": "created_at",
            "value_more_than": "2015-03-03",
            "value_less_than": "2015-03-04",
            "type" : "date"
        },
        {
            "field": "type",
            "value_in": "forward",
            "type" : "String"
        }
    ]
}
```

And saving these for future reference and querying on these when asked for. Please let me know, of you are familiar with a better format or can suggest some improvement overall.

Comment: What is the problem in saving the where condition as it is in a plain string form?

Comment: In that case I have to parse those strings to find, say whether query was ran for a particular date. Want to have a structured approach, queries can be little complex as well.